# DNA not supporting linear genealogy between grandparent, child and grandson?

Tags: dna

I am his grandmother and should have 300 or more cMs connection. However, we share only 18 or so cMs. My son, (my grandson's father), shares only 17.2 cMs.

What's up?

Comment: Hi Carolyn, can you please [edit] your question including the website or tools you are using to assess the dna matches. As I see it, either your son and grandson are not your son and grandson, or there is some sort of error in the data or the way you are comparing them. A grandparent should share over 1000 cM with a grandson, and a parent should share over 3000 cM with her son.

Comment: Hi, Carolyn -- welcome to G&FH.SE!  I too would like to know the company or companies involved.  Did you all test at the same company? How are you comparing your results?